# C++ Accessing Another Class Member

Tags: c++, class, object

I have a Question About Classes and objects. First this is my program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

class Class1{
    private:
        int x;
    public:
        Class1();
        void Display();

};
class Class2{
    private:
        double z;
    public:
        Class2();
        void Display();
        Class2 Add(Class1);
};

Class1::Class1(){   x = 1;  }
Class2::Class2(){   z = 5;  }
void Class1::Display(){ cout<<x<<"\n";  }
void Class2::Display(){ cout<<z<<"\n";  }
Class2 Class2::Add(Class1 t){
    Class2 y;
    y.z = t.x + z;
    return y;
}

int main(){

    Class1 ob1; // ob1 = 1 //
    Class2 ob2,ob_x; // ob2 = 5  | ob_x = 5 //  
    ob_x = ob2.Add(ob1); // Add ob + ob1 and Assigned them to ob_x //
    ob_x.Display();

    cout<<endl;
    getche();
    return 0;
}
```

I guess you know where is the error , **How can I access another class member ?**
I mean We Didn't learn that in University , All We know till know is that simple . Can I do that with another global function that can access both classes ? Please if can helpwith little tips , and thank's

Comment: Ever heard of getter/setter methods?

Comment: Here's a tutorial to get started http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14764412/how-to-access-member-function-of-one-class-inside-another-class?rq=1), and the other million questions about this topic 1st, before asking a new one!

Comment: You mean `GetElement()` method and `SetValue()` , like that ? but how can that help ?

Comment: @user3723837 _'but how can that help ?'_ Providing access to the underlying internal private data member?!? What's your particular problems understanding this principle??

Comment: I understand that properl.But I mean how can you return a value when you access another class attributes?

Comment: @user3723837 Reusing their _getter/setter_ methods maybe??

Comment: @user3723837: No you don´t. Make a getter method in A. This method is part of A and therefore can access the private variable x of A. If the method decides to return the value...everything else can get it by calling the method.

Comment: Bold suggestion I know, but have you considered asking your university lecturer / tutor for help? Presumably that is what they are paid for. Stackoverflow isn't really suitable for learning a language.

Comment: It is work , Thank's For ALL your help guys.This is the Solution.
In Class1 Add `int getdata(){return x;}`
And in Class2  `Class2 Add(Class1 t){
       Class2 y;
       y.z = t.getdata() + z;
       return y;
      }`

Thank's Again For helping. I Hope if anyone have the same problem , See this post's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add a getter method `int get_x()` to `Class1`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

class Class1{
    private:
        int x;
    public:
        Class1();
        void Display();
    int get_x();

};

int Class1::get_x()
{
 return x;
}

class Class2{
    private:
        double z;
    public:
        Class2();
        void Display();
        Class2 Add(Class1);
};

Class1::Class1(){   x = 1;  }
Class2::Class2(){   z = 5;  }
void Class1::Display(){ cout<<x<<"\n";  }
void Class2::Display(){ cout<<z<<"\n";  }
Class2 Class2::Add(Class1 t){
    Class2 y;
    y.z = t.get_x() + z;
    return y;
}

int main(){

    Class1 ob1; // ob1 = 1 //
    Class2 ob2,ob_x; // ob2 = 5  | ob_x = 5 //  
    ob_x = ob2.Add(ob1); // Add ob + ob1 and Assigned them to ob_x //
    ob_x.Display();

    cout<<endl;
    getche();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -4):

You make `x` `private` in the class, meaning you cannot access it from another class.  This is why your program is giving errors.  Make it `public`, then your program will start working.

Comment: That works, but what if he doesn't want it to be public?

Comment: Thank's but we learn in University that there is a risk when we make a variable as public , I wrong or what ?

Comment: The risk is that you can make semantical errors without the compiler complaining. etc.

Comment: @user3723837: You aren't wrong; making it public does carry risks.

Comment: @user3595398: Your post is barely understandable in a normal reading speed.

Comment: @user3595398 _'Make it public'_ That's blatantly wrong advice, sorry!

Comment: then tell another method by which we can run the program with out making x public.. u can use a private member out side the class

Comment: it can be another method that we use inheritance and make x variable protected

Comment: No you can´t use private vars outside of the class, and not in inherited ones too. There is no need for protected either. What´s o hard to understand with getter methods?

Comment: @deviantfan To be honest, I doubt his University will care if he makes the variable public since they never explained to him WHY it is a bad idea (most of the time) to make variables public. The University just told him to make variables private and now he is confused as to why he can't access them from a different class...*sigh*.

Comment: @user3595398 _'then tell another method by which we can run the program with out making x public'_ as mentioned _getter/setter_ methods ...